# Finding data based on existing data using livedata and ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a ViewModel, and in the ViewModel I call the api to get the data,
In the `getLeaguesBySeasons` method I got the data that I wanted and pushed it into a `LiveData`, but now I want to do a search function based on that data, So in the `onFilterLeague` method how do I do it, here who can you help me to solve this problem.

Following is the code inside my ViewModel:

```
class ChooseLeagueViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val api: RemoteRepositoryImpl,
    private val database: LocalRepositoryImpl
) :
    BaseViewModel() {

    private var _leaguesSelected = mutableListOf<Response>()

    val events: LiveData<Event<String>>
        get() = _events
    private val _events = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()

    private val _response = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Response>>>()
    val response: LiveData<Resource<List<Response>>> = _response

    fun getLeaguesBySeasons() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _response.postValue(Resource.loading(null))
            try {
                val response = api.getLeaguesBySeasons(2021)
                val list = response.response
                list?.let {
                    _response.postValue(Resource.success(it))
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                _response.postValue(Resource.error(e.toString(), null))
            }

        }
    }

    fun onFilterLeague(query: String) {

    }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can filter the data in `_response` live data and store it in new live data. This would make `_response` the source of truth for the ViewModel and the new live data as the source of truth for the view.

Answer (score 1):

Your live data object, in this case _response, will have the last 'pushed' data. So calling _response.value will give you current value. Note that calling this method on a background thread does not guarantee that the latest value set will be received.

From this point you can use filter,find,map or whatever other functions you require on the most recent data and push that to the latest live data results  which your observers should be reacting to in order to update the UI.

Comment: Did you mean something like this code: ```  fun onFilterLeague(query: String) {
        _response.map {
            var datas = it.data
            datas?.filter { item ->
                query == item.league?.name
            }
        }
    }   ```

Comment: _response.value.map {

....your code to do your filtering/sorting/whatever

}

The important bit is the "_response.value" to get the latest value from your live data object.